# Combine two sorted iterators in O(1) time

Tags: java, iterator

I was asked the following question in an interview:

> Combine two iterators over their sorted contents such that the
>   resulting iterator should iterate over the combination of these 2
>   iterators in sorted order in O(1) time (these iterators iterate over a
>   String).

I wrote the below code but I'm sure it doesn't perform in O(1) time. What advice do you have for matching the constraints set by the interview question?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class iteratorCombine {

// assumption1: elements are hardcoded
// assumption2: both iterators have equal number of elements
public static void main(String[] args) {

    iteratorCombine testObj = new iteratorCombine();
    Set<String> firstSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> secondSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> combinedSet;
    firstSet = testObj.storeElements1(firstSet);
    secondSet = testObj.storeElements2(secondSet);

    Iterator<String> it1 = firstSet.iterator();
    Iterator<String> it2 = secondSet.iterator();

    combinedSet = testObj.combine(it1, it2);

    // output
    Iterator<String> itComb = combinedSet.iterator();
    while(itComb.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(itComb.next());
    }

}

public Set<String> storeElements1(Set<String> firstSet){
    firstSet.add("first3");
    firstSet.add("first1");
    firstSet.add("first2");
    return firstSet;
}

public Set<String> storeElements2(Set<String> secondSet){
    secondSet.add("second3");
    secondSet.add("second1");
    secondSet.add("second2");
    return secondSet;
}

public Set<String> combine(Iterator<String> it1, Iterator<String>it2){
    String firstEle, secondEle;
    Set<String> combinedSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
        firstEle = it1.next();
        secondEle = it2.next();
        combinedSet.add(firstEle+secondEle);
    }
    return combinedSet;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can just paste code in, select it all, and Ctrl+K to make it a code block

Comment: Is the creation of the iterator supposed to be `O(1)`, or do you have as much time as you want to create the iterator, but it has to function in `O(1)`?

Comment: You're going to need to create a new class that implements `Iterator`; you won't be able to reuse an iterator from somewhere else.

Comment: This is simply the `merge()` part of mergesort. You will need to create a new `class` implementing `Iterator`.

Comment: How can *any* iterator be O(1), if there can be any number of elements? You simply can't iterate over an arbitrary-length sequence in O(1) time, regardless of implementation. Iterating over a sequence of length N will take N calls to `next()`...

Comment: @BoristheSpider merge is O(n)

Comment: @SleimanJneidi you're right. But This _cannot_ be `O(1)` - `O(n)` is the best you can do for iteration. Creation of the merging `Iterator` would of course be `O(1)` so maybe that's what the OP means...

Comment: @SleimanJneidi merge is O(n), but not determininig the minimum of two elements. the clue is that both iterators are already sorted. To "iterate" over both in order, you just have to return the minimum/maximum (depending on the order) of the current iterator-items in each iteration-step. I have to agree though that it is easy to misunderstand the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is only possible if the source is already sorted, and hence merge step in O(n) is required beforehand

Comment: @BoristheSpider As someone who asks a very similar interview question, I'm nearly positive the goal is an iterator that you can create in O(1) for which each call to `next()` takes O(1) time.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yup - that would be `merge`...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, but you need to implement it as an `Iterator`, instead of just as the normal `merge` step of mergesort, which is generally implemented on arrays or lists.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi No, why would I?  It's entirely possible to do without any O(n) parts.  I would point to an implementation, but I don't just want to give it away.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi of course not. Merge is just checking the head of each `Iterator` and take whichever is smaller/bigger depending on order. So the `Iterator` would merge on the fly so to speak.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi: No, the question as written talks about *iterating over it* in O(1) time - not creating the iterator. And that's just not feasible. Louis's "make each `next()` call O(1)" is reasonable, but not "iterate over all of it in O(1)".

Comment: @JonSkeet Given that this was an interview question, I strongly suspect that's just a misunderstanding on the OP's part.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I agree. But basically, we need the OP to come back and clarify.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it's a good question - I might just have to nick it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider and what do you do with element that is smaller? you discard it?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi why? Keep it and return it when it becomes bigger. As I said, this is the same logic as the merge step of a mergesort.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: One interesting point is that the .NET interfaces are designed in a way (Current/MoveNext()) which makes this simpler than than Java (next()/hasNext()).

Comment: @JonSkeet Exactly, there is no way to peek in iterator

Comment: @JonSkeet interesting - so `Current` returns `T` and doesn't move and `MoveNext` is `void` and moves the "pointer"? I guess that leads to fewer "called `next()` twice" errors?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi just _store_ it. Not overly complicated.

Comment: This is in fact a very good question, which makes me think of another question... Is it allright to keep state (in this case, the minimum element) inside an iterator? Are iterators expected to hold state?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner `Iterator` _by definition_ hold state!

Comment: @BoristheSpider I mean, apart from where they point to

Comment: @BoristheSpider thats if you were allowed to use an extra space, a min heap for example, which is similar to external merge sort

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it's not holding any more state than that - it's holding the current element in each of two `Collection`s.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I don't know what a minheap has to do with it. And the space is still `O(1)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Mmm, alright, just thought that maybe it was too much for an iterator, but I think you are right

Comment: @BoristheSpider: `MoveNext()` returns whether or not the move was successful, i.e. it returns `false` when you've already reached the end. So a foreach is effectively `while (iterator.MoveNext()) { T item = iterator.Current; ... }` (but with disposal...)

Comment: @BoristheSpider so you gonna extend iterator to have peak function?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi 1) take two iterators. 2) take the head from both. 3) while neither is empty; 3.1) return the lower/higher of the two values; 3.2) take the next element from the appropriate iterator (if not empty); 4) once one empties simply follow the other. There is no peek required!

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think I've coded up your idea :)

Answer (score 6):

I believe that you can't do it if you don't extend `iterator` and support a `peek` function. Such an iterator is not that hard. Here is a way for doing it.

```
static class PeekingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final Iterator<T> iterator;
    private T temp;

    public PeekingIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public T peek() {
        //if there is no peek, advance the iterator and store its value, return the peek otherwise
        if(temp==null){ 
            temp = this.iterator.next();
        }
        return temp;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
       //if we already have a peek,return it and nullify it, otherwise do normal next()
        if(temp!=null){
            T t = temp;
            temp = null;
            return t;
        }else{
            return this.iterator.next();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.iterator.hasNext() || temp!=null;
    }
}
```

Once you can peek, the rest is easy, you can build `SortedIterator` using two peeking iterators,  peek both iterators and advance the iterator that has the smaller element.

```
static class SortedIterator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterator<T>{
    private final PeekingIterator<T> peekingIterator1;
    private final PeekingIterator<T> peekingIterator2;

    SortedIterator(Iterator<T> source1, Iterator<T> source2){
        peekingIterator1 = new PeekingIterator<>(source1);
        peekingIterator2 = new PeekingIterator<>(source2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return peekingIterator1.hasNext() || peekingIterator2.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(!peekingIterator1.hasNext()){
            return peekingIterator2.next();
        }
        if(!peekingIterator2.hasNext()){
            return peekingIterator1.next();
        }

        T peek1 = peekingIterator1.peek();
        T peek2 = peekingIterator2.peek();
        if(peek1.compareTo(peek2)<0){
            return peekingIterator1.next();
        }
        return peekingIterator2.next();
    }
}
```

The analysis are obvious here, `SortedIterator.next` and `SortedIterator.hasNext` run in constant time.

Comment: Nicely done, although a null element in one of the input iterators may wreak havoc.

Comment: The peeking iterator might be overkill - but in an interview situation this shows an extra skill. If you were to mention the Decorator Pattern then I imagine the interviewer would be mighty impressed. Good work! (For the implementation of `PeekingIterator` see [Guava's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#peekingIterator(java.util.Iterator)) - it differs slightly in that it uses a `boolean` to avoid those nasty `null` checks.)

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks, I wasn't aware of Guava's PeekingIterator

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful!!

Comment: The issue of a null element is not really a concern in this particular case, since it is a stated precondition that the iterators are sorted, which implies the elements can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case but instead of only 2 iterators, I had to merge a dynamic number of iterators. The number of iterators can be more than 2. e.g., 3 iterators, 4 iterators, or more.

I used the same solution as [Sleiman Jneidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822588/sleiman-jneidi) suggested. I modified the SortedIterator to support multiple iterators and also support sorting in ascending or descending order based on need.

For the `PeekingIterator`, I used Apache commons collection's Peeking iterator.
Here is my sorted iterator if someone may need to merge multiple sorted iterators, they can refer to this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.PeekingIterator;

/**
 * This class is special implementation of Iterator.
 * It lets multiple sorted iterators to be merged to a single sorted iterator.
 * It will use given comparator to compare values from multiple iterators. 
 * 
 */
public class SortedMergedIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    /**
     * Comparator that will be used to compare values from across the iterators.
     */
    private final Comparator<? super T> comparator;
    
    
    /**
     * List of sorted iterators which are required to be merged to a single sorted iterator.
     */
    private final List<PeekingIterator<T>> peekingIterators;
    
    
    /**
     * By default the sort order will be considered as ascending order.
     *
     * It this flag is set to true, the elements will be sorted in descending order.
     * In this case, it is pre-requisite that all the iterators being passed should be sorted in ascending order.
     */
    private final boolean sortOrderDescending;

    
    public SortedMergedIterator(final Comparator<? super T> comparator, final List<Iterator<T>> iterators) {
        this(comparator, iterators, false);
    }
    
    
    public SortedMergedIterator(final Comparator<? super T> comparator, final List<Iterator<T>> iterators, final boolean sortOrderDescending) {
        this.comparator = comparator;           
        this.peekingIterators = iterators.stream().map(iterator -> new PeekingIterator<>(iterator)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.sortOrderDescending = sortOrderDescending;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {

        // If at least one of the child iterator has next element.
        return this.peekingIterators.stream().anyMatch(Iterator::hasNext);
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {

        // Peek next value from all the iterators.
        final List<T> peekedValues = this.peekingIterators.stream().map(PeekingIterator::peek).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Find the minimum value from all the peeked values.
        final T minElement = peekedValues
                .stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .min(this.sortOrderDescending ? this.comparator.reversed() : this.comparator)
                .orElse(null);
        
        // Return the next element from an iterator for which minimum value is found.
        return this.peekingIterators.get(peekedValues.indexOf(minElement)).next();
    }

}
```

Example of using this iterator:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Example of ascending order sorted iterators.
        final List<Integer> list1 = Lists.newArrayList(4,7,11,12,16);
        final List<Integer> list2 = Lists.newArrayList(1,3,5,10,15);
        final List<Integer> list3 = Lists.newArrayList(6,8,13,18,20);
        final List<Integer> list4 = Lists.newArrayList(2,9,14,17,19);
        
        final SortedMergedIterator<Integer> sortedIterator =
                new SortedMergedIterator<>(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a), Arrays.asList(list1.iterator(), list2.iterator(), list3.iterator(), list4.iterator()));

        while (sortedIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(sortedIterator.next());
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        
        // Example of descending order sorted iterators.
        final List<Integer> list5 = Lists.newArrayList(16,12,11,7,4);
        final List<Integer> list6 = Lists.newArrayList(15,10,5,3,1);
        final List<Integer> list7 = Lists.newArrayList(20,18,13,8,6);
        final List<Integer> list8 = Lists.newArrayList(19,17,14,9,2);
        
        final SortedMergedIterator<Integer> descSortedIterator =
                new SortedMergedIterator<>(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a), Arrays.asList(list5.iterator(), list6.iterator(), list7.iterator(), list8.iterator()), true);

        while (descSortedIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(descSortedIterator.next());
        }
    }
```